# How accurate is the patched conic approximation when performing a Hohmann interplanetary transfer?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, hohmann-transfer, trajectory-design

I've been making a Mathematica script whereby a spacecraft is transferred from Earth to Mars using a [Hohmann interplanetary transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit) by means of a [patched conic approximation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patched_conic_approximation)

As far as I can tell all of the equations and numbers should be correct, yet when running the code the spacecraft doesn't make it to Mars. Without getting into any detail of the code (that will have to be for the Mathematica SX forums), I wanted to ask how accurate the patched conic approximation really is. If all of the numbers are correct should I be able to run the code and the spacecraft will hit Mars, or is it supposed to be used to find a rough trajectory to another planet? I understand the inherent inaccuracies with the approximation since it considers everything in terms of individual 2-body problems, and so thought I might be a little too hopeful when I thought it would get me to Mars.

[image]

EDIT: Okay, I think my initial post used an incorrect angle for applying the delta-v impulse which I have since fixed (I think!). I made a second program that looked at just the Earth and spacecraft upon departure to confirm whether my angle was correct and this is what I got (the spacecraft doesn't actually pass through the green circle (Earth). The green circle is just the position of Earth at the start of the simulation):

[image]

As you can see, the spacecraft's escape velocity is parallel to the Earth's velocity which is a good start. I got the correct angle by finding the angle of the Earth's velocity vector using phi = arctan(v_y/v_x), the "impulse angle" (not too sure what to call it) by using beta = arccos(1/e) and then using theta = phi + beta + pi when finding the x- and y-components for delta-v = v_p - v_c (where v_x and v_y are the x- and y-components of the Earth's velocity respectively, e is the escape hyperbola's eccentricity and v_p and v_c are the spacecraft's periapse speed and circular orbit speed about Earth respectively).

Unfortunately, when running the full program again in the Sun's frame of reference I found the following:

1) Roughly half-period of spacecraft orbit about Sun
[image]

2) Full period of spacecraft orbit about Sun
[image]

P.S. The equations I'm using are from Orbital Mechanics for Engineering Students by Howard Curtis.

UPDATE: Solution to Earth-Mars interplanetary transfer using Lambert solver (some much needed coding help was given my the Mathematica SX forums).

[image]

Comment: What does your plot signify? In what manner is the craft not making it to Mars?

Comment: The plot signifies a top down view of the orbits of Earth (inner circle) and Mars (outer circle) about the Sun (located at (0,0)), as well as the path the spacecraft makes from Earth to Mars, which was made by numerically integrating Newton's Law of Gravitation for 4 bodies. I was hoping to see the spacecraft either get pulled into an orbit about Mars, or have its orbital path highly perturbed by coming into Mars' sphere of influence, but as can be seen it unfortunately passed harmlessly past Mars without even getting close (relative to astronomical distances it missed by a long shot!).

Comment: What are the times involved? When the spacecraft makes its closest approach to Mars's orbit, is Mars also at that point in its orbit? If so, what is the distance of closet approach? I don't know this area, but these might help someone else figure what's going on. In addition, you might try flagging this for migration to [space.se] or [astronomy.se], as those communities might be able to give you a better answer than this one.

Comment: I set the date of departure as the 30th of March 2001 which I found in a table online (it was said to be within the window of opportunity). I made an animation of the above plot to see how close the spacecraft got to Mars and it looks like the craft arrived too late (the angle made between their radius vectors is about 10 degrees once the spacecraft reaches aphelion) so maybe the departure date was wrong or my equations were wrong. Can anyone confirm if the above date that I used would have been within a correct launch window?

Comment: This is the website I used to find the launch windows, for those who are interested: http://clowder.net/hop/railroad/EMa.htm

Comment: Is "patched conic approximation" the technical phrase for what KSP does?

Comment: Could you please give a link to your simulation, it would be really interesting :)

Comment: Thanks for linking to my website for Hohmann launch windows. My model assumes circular, coplanar orbits. Mars orbit is noticeably elliptical.

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty hard to tell what's going on with just a plot, especially since you show an entire spacecraft orbit instead of just the half that you intended to be the transfer.  In any case, one thing that I'm seeing that doesn't look right is that the spacecraft trajectory goes inside Earth's orbit.  That shouldn't happen (at least not to the degree shown).  That indicates that your departure velocity from Earth ($V_\infty$) has the wrong direction.

Are you integrating from a low Earth orbit?  It takes some care to time that correctly so you get the right $V_\infty$ direction.

While the patched conic is just an approximation, if done correctly it should get you much closer to the orbit of Mars than what you show.  You should not be able to see a gap at the resolution of that plot.

When you say in the comments "I was hoping to see the spacecraft either get pulled into an orbit about Mars ...", that's not possible.  Without a propulsive maneuver at Mars, the spacecraft will fly by, as indicated in the rest of your sentence "... or have its orbital path highly perturbed by coming into Mars' sphere of influence".  That will happen if you get the timing right for when you depart Earth.

*Update:*

Ok, that's an improvement.

Now you need to account for the eccentricity of the orbit of Mars.  The spacecraft should have an aphelion that corresponds to the distance of Mars from the Sun at the planned time of the encounter.  It will help to also take into account the eccentricity of the Earth's orbit, in particular the distance of the Earth from the Sun at the time of departure.

*Side note:*

Beware the perils of the numerical derivative.  Take care to not use *too* small of a $\Delta T$.  Here is an example in Mathematica when trying to determine the velocity vector of Earth using Earth position data.  $\Delta T$ is on the x-axis in seconds.

`f[dt_?NumericQ] := 
  AstronomicalData["Earth", {"Position", {2001, 3, 30, 0, 0, 1 + dt}}] - 
  AstronomicalData["Earth", {"Position", {2001, 3, 30, 0, 0, 1}}]`

`LogLinearPlot[f[dt][[1]]/dt, {dt, 0.001, 100}]`

[image: numerical derivative noise plot]

Comment: When you say I must take into account the eccentricity of Mars and Earth, I'm guessing you mean I must change the equation for v_infinity which is given by v_infinity = sqrt(mu_sun/R_earth(sqrt(2R_mars/(R_mars+R_earth))-1)? Would I set R_earth to Earth's heliocentric radius at spacecraft departure, and R_mars to Mars' heliocentric radius at spacecraft arrival? Currently they are both set to their heliocentric radii at departure.

P.S. I apologise for the horrible looking equation, it's tough to make them look nice in a little box like this.

Comment: I can't quite make out your equation, but yes, use Earth's heliocentric radius at departure, and Mars' heliocentric radius at arrival.

Comment: By the way, you can use $\TeX$ equations in comments, e.g. $\sqrt{\mu_S\over r_1}\left(\sqrt{2r_2\over r_1+r_2}-1\right)$.  I think that's the equation you meant, but it looks like you're missing a parenthesis.

Comment: A second by the way: that equation assumes that the starting orbit is circular.  Earth's orbit is not circular (in fact no orbit is really), and so you need to account for the Earth's actual velocity at departure.

Comment: Hmmm, I've been doing a little more reading and it seems like a pure Hohmann transfer is not usually used in interplanetary travel as it's not always practical and instead a solution to Lambert's problem is found. Should I maybe consider moving over to something like that?

Comment: Yes, to find the optimal connection between two real orbits with eccentricities, inclinations, and arguments of periapsis, you would use the Lambert's problem solution.  However I recommend that you get the Hohmann transfer between two coplanar elliptical orbits working first, and then graduate to the Lambert's problem solution.

Comment: Well said, going back to the Hohmann transfer then, how would I take into account Earth's velocity at departure in the above equation? Currently I've been using Mathematica's AstronomicalData function to get the initial positions of Earth and Mars in space and then I've found their initial velocities using a central difference on their positions over a relatively small time period. These values are then put in as initial conditions for an N-body simulation.

Comment: That will work.  Make sure that you pick a large enough $\Delta T$ to get a good number of significant digits in the differences.  Alternatively you can use the orbital elements from `AstronomicalData[]`, e.g. `"SemimajorAxis"`, `"Eccentricity"`, etc. and propagate the two-body solutions for the Earth, Moon, and Mars in closed form.  You really only need to integrate the trajectory of the spacecraft.

Comment: Large ΔT? I thought we would want ΔT to be as small as possible in order to bring it as close to an infinitesimal as we can, or am I misunderstanding something? Currently I have ΔT = 0.001 and, for example, the central difference I used to calculate Earth's initial velocity is $$v[1] = ((AstronomicalData[
       "Earth", {"Position", {2001, 3, 30, 0, 0, 1.001}}] - 
      AstronomicalData[
       "Earth", {"Position", {2001, 3, 30, 0, 0, 
         0.999}}]))/(2 (0.001));$$

Comment: Perfect example.  0.002 seconds is way too small of a $\Delta T$ for the data you are using.  Yes, you want a small $\Delta T$, but it is possible to pick _too_ small of a $\Delta T$ that samples noise in the lower significant digits of your data.  Run this in Mathematica to see what I'm talking about: `f[dt_] := AstronomicalData["Earth", {"Position", {2001, 3, 30, 0, 0, 1 + dt}}] - AstronomicalData["Earth", {"Position", {2001, 3, 30, 0, 0, 1}}]` and `LogLinearPlot[f[dt][[1]]/dt, {dt, 0.001, 100}]`.  From that plot, it looks like around 10 seconds is a good $\Delta T$.

Comment: I added the plot to the answer.

Comment: Oh wow, I always thought that one needed to get ΔT as small as possible. If anomalies like you've shown do occur, how would I know what value of ΔT would be appropriate for use (not just in this case but for any case where I have to choose a ΔT when using a finite difference)? Is there a standardised method, or do I just have to make an ad hoc check using the formula you produced above?

Comment: You need to check each time, since it depends on the data you're using.  There is an `ND` (numerical derivative) function in the `NumericalCalculus` package you can try.  I've never tried it, but it may do the checking for you.  Even then I would still check myself to make sure the answers make sense.  Doing numerical derivatives is fraught with peril.

Comment: When I use your error formula in the form of a central difference I get a very difference story, although I do get a error saying the following: `Part::partd: "Part specification 0[[1]] is longer than depth of object."` 

This is the error checking formula I used for the central difference:`f[dt_] := 
 AstronomicalData[
   "Earth", {"Position", {2001, 3, 30, 0, 0, 1 + dt}}] - 
  AstronomicalData["Earth", {"Position", {2001, 3, 30, 0, 0, 1 - dt}}] 
LogLinearPlot[f[dt][[1]]/2 dt, {dt, 0.001, 100}]`

Comment: You need `/(2 dt)`, not `/2 dt`.  The latter is multiplying by `dt` not dividing by it.  Once you fix that, it's still not apples and apples, since now your "`dt`" is actually half of the real `dt`.  To have a consistent meaning for `dt`, you need to do `1+dt/2` and `1-dt/2`, and the divide the difference by `dt` instead of `(2 dt)`.

Comment: By the way, you can fix the part specification error by restricting the evaluation of the function to numeric arguments with: `f[dt_?NumericQ]:=`...  I should have done that initially.

Comment: And in case I'm not being clear, _don't do it this way_.  Use the orbital elements instead along with the position and calculate the velocity directly.  That will give you a much more accurate result, and will not depend on the vagaries of what $\Delta T$ you pick for a numerical derivative.

Comment: Hi there Mark, I hope you're still around, sorry for my disappearance these last few months! I've come back to this problem and tried finding the instantaneous velocity of Earth and Mars using the orbital elements but am having some trouble. I found this link online which gives instructions on how to find velocities using orbital elements: http://www.cdeagle.com/omnum/pdf/demosvoe.pdf. The only parts of the puzzle that I can't complete, though, are finding the true anomaly v (nu) and argument of perigee w (omega) and Mathematica's AstronomicalData doesn't seem to have them either.

Comment: The first five elements of `AstronomicalData["Earth", "OrbitRules"]` are the usual non-time-dependent orbital elements.  The sixth element, the true anomaly, is a measure of the position of the object in the orbit.  You will have to solve for that given the moment in time you want the true anomaly for, and the position of the object at that time, using the "Position" property as you have been doing.

Comment: Looking at the true anomaly wiki, it requires an eccentricity vector that is dotted with its radius vector, but Mathematica only gives an eccentricity magnitude. Is there a way to get an eccentricity vector without having to use velocity (which seems to be the only way at the moment)?

Comment: You don't have to do it that way, but you can make an eccentricity vector by rotating `{e,0,0}` by the Euler angles $\Omega$, $i$, and $\omega$.

Comment: Aha! Sorry if this is a stupid question (I haven't studied Astrodynamics), but does this mean that the eccentricity, and all other orbital elements for that matter, given by Mathematica are in the Perifocal frame, and this "rotation" puts it in the Heliocentric frame? I found a rotation matrix called QxX (took a while to put in all those trig functions!) and multiplied it by {e,0,0} and this is what my output was: {-0.01604561, -0.00466582, 1*10^-8}. Does this look correct?

Comment: The orbit in its plane is described by $a$ and $e$.  The orbit plane is rotated from XY to where it actually is by $\Omega$, $i$, and $\omega$ (which are the Euler angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ for that rotation respectively).  Those three orbital elements aren't "in" a plane.  They describe how to transform from one plane to another.

Comment: Hi Mark. I thought it would be rude not to give you an update on what I've been doing, since you've been kind enough to help me so much. I've since moved to a Lambert solver using a basic bisection method, as the Hohmann transfer was a little too frustrating, and I felt it was far too limiting with regards to transfer opportunities (as I'm sure you're more than aware). I've also started using JPL's Horizons ephemeris for initial conditions which has made the numerical model a lot more accurate. Now I just need to get ephemeris data in a more automated manner, but that's for another topic!

Comment: For that purpose, I recommend the [SPICE toolkit](http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit.html), along with a recent ephemeris file such as [DE430](http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/planets/de430.bsp).  You'll also need a [recent leap seconds kernel](http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/lsk/naif0010.tls).

Answer (score 4):

If departure and destination points are 180 degrees apart (as in a Hohmann transfer), Lambert iterations will give a polar heliocentric transfer orbit. That is an orbit with inclination 90º. Obviously such a transfer orbit would take huge plane change expense at departure and destination.

This can be mitigated by using a broken plane transfer orbit. See [Deboning The Porkchop Plot](http://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.com/2013/01/deboning-porkchop-plot.html).

If you stay in the ecliptic plane, you can miss Mars by a good margin. The only places where Mars comes close to the ecliptic plane is around the ascending and descending nodes.

Comment: The other solution, which is the one actually used, is to simply not force the departure and destination to be 180° apart.  You pick your departure and destination dates to be around the minima on either side of the ridge on the porkchop plot, called a Type 1 and Type 2 trajectory, for less than or more than 180° respectively.  No broken plane maneuver is needed.

Comment: There are two types of direction change to consider here. Plane change as well as flight path angle change. For coplanar orbits you would want the transfer orbit to be tangent to the departure and destination orbit. Since Mars has a noticeably elliptical orbit, the tangent transfer orbit can be more or less than 180 degrees, but usually in that neighborhood.

Comment: To avoid plane change expense you want launch and or departure to be near a descending or ascending node. Sometimes this can result in decidedly un-Hohmann like orbits where the transfer orbit only covers 100º from departure to destination. This would result in a major change for heliocentric flight path angle.